# FFMPEG - What are some recommended parameters for x265 (libx265)?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on re-encoding some footage (x264), including some grainy footage.  I am interested in CRF-only bitrate management (I want to avoid artifacts during demanding scenes).
What are recommended parameters to be set instead of leaving them at their defaults?

Here is what I got so far, pretty simple:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf unsharp=3:3:1 -c:v libx265 -tune:v grain -crf 24 -c:a copy out.mkv
```

(this example has grain tune as many files are grainy, and without it it washes it out and all the "detail by noise" is lost + I am applying a light sharpening filter, I find there is always a room to sharpen a bit without causing noticeable sharpening artifacts)

If I am not mistaken all the params one does consider are ones contained in the [presets](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/presets.html), but is there some other or one of those which is a good practice to adjust manually to achieve a better result? I was wondering specifically about P,I,B-frames and AQ (but I guess there are some other as well).

Comment: Why re-encode in the first place?

Comment: I am looking at reducing the file size and use the x265's better compression (i.e. less noticeable for our sight) to reduce the size (I would like to achieve 50-65% of original size). I am slowly running out of space on my storage. But I find the first reason good for a long-term storage purposes as well, handling/migrating smaller files is always more comfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults are what the developers recomend. But every video is  different, and could be improved with custom settings. There is no “Better default”, because it could be worse on a different file. It can’t be know by anyone without the video file, and the preferences of the viewer.

Comment: I see, so if I want "something better", then basically unless I want to test specific parameters, then choosing a different preset is the way to go?